# Look up vertex' attributes, given a 3D texture position (in shader nodes)

Tags: node-editor, shaders, volumetrics, texture-coordinates

Is there a way to access the (possibly interpolated) vertex attribute of the closest vertices in a shader node, given a 3D position? In a CPU-based program, I'd use a k-d tree and search for the nearest neighbors, but how do I do this in a shader node graph?

Context:
I have a texture node (Voronoi) from which I use the "Position" output to segment my material into Voronoi cells:
[image]
I would like to use a vertex attribute (stored in a vertex color) to determine whether a *whole* cell should be "on" or "off", i.e. the vertex attribute acts as a "threshold" of sorts. Is there a way to sample the (closest) vertex color at a specific 3D position?

The only idea I had so far was to interpolate the vertex color into a volume and then sample from that volume at the position given by the Voronoi texture... is that possible?

(For reference, I have a related question that gave rise to this one. I have created this new one because the other one is much more general: [Blending two procedural "reptile-scale" textures - at scale edges](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/233492/blending-two-procedural-reptile-scale-textures-at-scale-edges))

Comment: Could you bake it to a UV texture, then sample that texture based on your voronoi thing?

Comment: @ReinisMazeiks I'm not sure I understand. I jut tried baking the vertex colors into a texture (after UV-unwrapping), that works. But now that image can be sampled using UV coordinates, while the voronoi coordinates are 3D vectors. How would I use these 3D vectors to sample the image?

Comment: they don't need to be 3d vectors, you can also voronoi the 2d coordinates. this is what i meant https://imgur.com/bboSJTp