# How to drive the Scale of a Voronoi Texture with a Noise Texture (the brighter the noise the bigger the Voronoi-Scale)

Tags: texturing, transforms, dynamic

Sorry - I'm new to Blender and couldn't find an answer to this.

I have a Voronoi Texture (Distance to Edge) and would like to use a Noise Texture to set its Scale. So, where the noise is bright the 'Flakes' of the Voronoi should be big and where the noise is dark the scale of the Flakes should be small.

And this should happen dynamically. So I don't just want to mix two different sized Voronoi textures by blending them with a MixRGB but I would like to have the greyscale values of the Noise Texture gradually making the Voronoi 'Flakes' bigger.

[image]

[edit]
I should have shown this straight away - this is the effect I'm trying to achieve procedurally:
[image]

I hope this makes sense.

Thanks!
Ooly

Comment: You can use a *Map Range* node to convert the [0..1] values of the noise into  [4..40] values (for example). But I am not sure if the resulted transition fits your expectations: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3AUrm.jpg

Answer (score 3):

You can use a setup like this. Because you lose control of the scale of the Voronoi somewhat, make it big enough to see first by using a mapping node and scaling the X and Y by 20 or so. Make the scale smaller if you make the scale of the Noise Texture smaller or things will look weird. There is a degree of "finicky-ness" where you have to find a balance where there is not too much "undesired warping" - you'll see. I used a MixRGB node, mixing the Noise Texture with white to give another "control slider" over the strength of the influence to help with this. Still, there is a narrower range than I'd prefer where this looks good as opposed to strange. I hope you can find a size/scale that works for you.

[image: Voronoi]

Comment: Wow -  I'm overwhelmed by all the amazing answers! Thanks a lot, everyone!
@Christopher
I'll have a closer look into this. Thanks a lot - this is very helpful.

And I apologise, I should have added more context. There is probably a different approach which achieves what I'm trying to do. I will add a clarifying image to the original post.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

My solution is really tedious. Unfortunately my math knowledge is limited, so here is my solution with the little advantage that is has no "distortion":

Here you see the "evolution":

[image]

1. is just to show you my noise. It has a greater than node so you can see it clearer

[image]

2. is just to show you my voronoi.

[image]

3. mix the voronoi with the noise, in reality i just use the noise value to choose whether it takes the voronoi with the bigger or lower scale value.

[image]

4. if you add now more of these "less than" + "multiply add" + mix nodes you can get kind of "gradient" effect of the scale and it would look better. But yes, it is tedious. The only advantage is has, you have no "distortion effect". I am pretty sure Robin has a more elegant solution.

[image]

next step would look like this:

[image]

finally i found a not that tedious solution, but it has the disadvantage, that you "see" the edges...

here is the node setup:

[image]

result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the compliment, but I'm not sure, atm, can come up with anything better than masking-by-cell, as [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/229146/35559) or [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/233500/35559).. what would be nice would be something like @Christpopher Bennett 's answer that doesn't bend the boundaries: i.e. changing the concentration of Voronoi feature-points _without_ changing the metric along which the distance-to-nearest is measured. I think you may have to implement your own Voronoi to get the knife in.

Comment: This is great as well. Thanks a lot for posting this!
It gives me plenty to work on. Amazing what you guys come up with!

I also liked @Robin Betts second suggestion - the question is how to line up the smaller 'flakes' with the bigger ones. Okay - I'll have a go now. Thank you so so much, guys!

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking along the same lines as @Blunder; a *Map Range* node should do it if you can find the correct texture scales and a good range of values.  I modified the setup in the comment a little.  Here's the result:

[image]

The *Noise* scale is the scale of the distortion pattern, *To Min* is the overall *Voronoi* scale, and when the *Min* and *Max* values are closer to each other there is less distortion.